# Display a UIViewController inside a SwiftUI View

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to build a UIViewController wrapper to display UIViewControllers in SwiftUI. Right now I am getting

> Cannot preview in this file - unexpected error occurred

Which SwiftUI is already classic for misleading and vague error. Anyway here is my code for my wrapper class. It was hard to find this because most examples online are ViewControllers, not UIViewControllers.

```
struct WrapperUIView: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController


    let storyboard: String
    let VC: String

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WrapperUIView>) -> WrapperUIView.UIViewControllerType {

        //load the storyboard
        let loadedStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)


        //load the viewcontroller
        return loadedStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: WrapperUIView.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<WrapperUIView>) {

    }

}

struct HomeUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View{

        HomeUIView(storyboard: "Main", VC: "HomeViewController")
    }
}
```

So something is wrong here but I have no idea what.. here is the code that calls the above view.

```
struct TabMotherView: View{

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter = TabViewRouter()
    //@State var page = "Search"

    var body: some View{

        return VStack{
            if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Search"{
                //HseNearMissView()
                WrapperUIView(storyboard: "Main", VC: "HomeViewController")

            } else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "Documents" {


            CustomSwiftUIView()

        }
      }
    }

}
```

The "CustomSwiftUIView()" displays perfectly fine if I removed WrapperUIView(). That means my bug is definitely narrowed down to the WrapperUIView()

Any thoughts?

Comment: The `WrapperUIView` itself works properly. Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2. Just created Main.storyboard with a UIViewController having HomeViewController identifier and several controls, and used `WrapperUIView(storyboard: "Main", VC: "HomeViewController")` in SwiftUI `ContentView`.

Comment: Awesome Asperi, that actually helps a lot. I'll have to narrow this down as something else. Perhaps I'll try some tests but might delete this question if that works just fine.

Comment: Probably the issue is related to `viewRouter` object. What is the default value for `currentView` property?

Comment: I was able to get this to work.. by turning my computer off and on. Also @MidhunMp thanks for the help, "Search" was my default value.